# T-SQL Replace or Substitute in a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL script where I need to change the returning values. It is being stored in a view. The script is as follows:

```
WITH live AS
(
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Customer Name] ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) AS last_occ
        , CONVERT(INT,[Count]) AS CountInt   
    FROM [Database].[Table]           
)
SELECT *
FROM live
```

I need to squeeze

```
REPLACE([Column_name], 'orig_string', 'new_string')
```

somewhere but every location keeps returning an error.

Note: I need this to adapt to the original string so I wonder if I can use a `SWITCH` or `IF` function.

Comment: So *where* have you tried to put it? What were the errors you got? Also, why use a CTE here when there appears to be no need for it.

Answer (score 1):

> so now I'm only facing the remaining task how to encapsulate this into a condition

> `String 1 => Adjusted_String 1`
> `String 2 => Adjusted_String 2`
> `String 1 => Adjusted_String 1`
> `String 3 => Adjusted_String 3`
> `String 3 => Adjusted_String 3`
> `String 1 => Adjusted_String 1`

Probably simplest to just run the replace multiple times, if it won't cause unintended replacements

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(originalcolumn
  ,'String 1', 'Adjusted_String 1')
  ,'String 2', 'Adjusted_String 2')
  ,'String 3', 'Adjusted_String 3')
```

If you want to do it conditionally:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN originalcolumn LIKE '%String 1%' THEN REPLACE(originalcolumn, 'String 1', 'Adjusted_String 1')
    WHEN originalcolumn LIKE '%String 2%' THEN REPLACE(originalcolumn, 'String 2', 'Adjusted_String 2')
    WHEN originalcolumn LIKE '%String 3%' THEN REPLACE(originalcolumn, 'String 3', 'Adjusted_String 3')
  END as ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by:

```
    WITH live AS
            (
                SELECT * ,
                        
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Customer Name] ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) AS last_occ,
                        CONVERT(INT,[Count]) AS CountInt,
                        REPLACE([Column_name], 'orig_string', 'new_string') AS NewString    
                FROM [Database].[Table]
              
            )
                  SELECT * FROM live
```

Comment: You've either answered the question or you haven't, you can't ask a new question in your answer. And when you ask a new question please ensure this time you include a [mre] with sample data and desired results so its clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is this another question? If so, then it shouldn't be posted as an answer.